# Hysteresis Loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, plot

I am new to latex. I'm doing my MA thesis on Magnetic Materials. I don't know how to draw this diagram in LaTeX.
I would be grateful if you can help me with this image.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Clemens. I would like to ask you if you could add another tag to this question which is the name of this diagram. It is called Hysteresis Loop.

Comment: tags should't be too specific. The packages for plotting are the same regardless if you want to plot a hysteresis loop or some other plot. Some more details would be important to know: do you just want to have some schematic sketch or do you have specific data for you want to plot? Have you tried anything on your own already and if so what have you tried exactly? …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function as the sigmoid function to draw a beautiful hysteresis loop. Here an example using PGFPlots.

## Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[very thick,
                     samples = 100,
                     xlabel = H,
                     ylabel = B,
                     xmin = -7,
                     xmax = 7,
                     ymin = -4,
                     ymax = 4,
                     axis x line = middle,
                     axis y line = middle,
                     ticks = none]
            \addplot[dashed] plot (\x, 2.5);
            \addplot[dashed] plot (\x,-2.5);
            \addplot[red, name path=A] plot (\x, {5/(1 + exp(-1.7*\x+1.5))-2.5});
            \addplot[red, name path=B] plot (\x, {5/(1 + exp(-1.7*\x-1.5))-2.5});
            \addplot[red!20] fill between[of=A and B];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you have a real hysteresis loop data you can use PGFPlots to easily draw it.

## Result

[image]

Comment: Old answer, I know, but why do you mix TikZ and `pgfplots` plotting syntax? TikZ has `\draw plot (\x,f(\x);`, while `pgfplots` has `\addplot {f(x)};`, so I would expect `\addplot [dashed,samples=2] {2.5};` and `\addplot[red, name path=A] {5/(1 + exp(-1.7*x+1.5))-2.5};`

Comment: Little experience, I think.

Comment: I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex'.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.3 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}  ?

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=orange!70] (-3,-3) to [out=0,in=200,looseness=1.1] (3,3) to[out=180, in =20,looseness=1.1]
         (-3,-3);
    \draw[-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[below]{$H$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[left]{$B$};
    \draw[dashed] (-4,3) -- (4,3);
    \draw[dashed] (-4,-3) -- (4,-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way (using bazier curves)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=orange!70] (-3,-3) .. controls (2.5,-3) and (-0.5,3) .. (3,3)
             .. controls (-2.5,3) and (0.5,-3) ..(-3,-3);
    \draw[-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[below]{$H$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[left]{$B$};
    \draw[dashed] (-4,3) -- (4,3);
    \draw[dashed] (-4,-3) -- (4,-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is a small typo, too small to be edited: bazier instead of bezier

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Osjerick script a bit for the case of a hysteresis loop created by an electrical current experiment. We start with zero magnetization and no current (I also changed H and B by current I and magnetization M. Just a different alternative). Then adding current in one direction we get a magnetization following the initial path (in red). After this current is turned off to get to 0 current and some magnetization M, then the current is opposite to rich a saturation point (left bottom) and then off, and then back again in the "forward" direction. I also added arrows to point the historical development of the path, changed color and stretched the x axis.[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.0]
  \draw[fill=green!70,-latex, line width=1] (-3,-3) to [out=0,in=200,looseness=1.1] (3,3) 
  to[out=180, in =20,looseness=1.1] (-3,-3);
  \draw[color=red,-latex, line width=1, dotted] (0,0) to 
    [out=60,in=180,looseness=0.9] (3,3) ;
  \draw[-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[below]{$I$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[left]{$M$};
  \draw[dashed] (-4,3) -- (4,3);
  \draw[dashed] (-4,-3) -- (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```