# Dimension too large-errors by TikZ datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

This question is a continuation of a [similar one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350016/how-to-draw-a-hysteresis-loop-with-tikz-datavisualization).

My task is to draw two hysteresis loops in one graph. I took the function (which represents my hysteresis loops) from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275192/hysteresis-loop).

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks and grid = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{H}{\si{\A\per\m}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{B(H)}{\si{\tesla}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {left_soft, right_soft, left_hard, right_hard},
                       left_soft = {style = dashed,
                                    label in legend = {text = weichmagnetisch}
                                   },
                       right_soft = {style = dashed},
                       left_hard = {label in legend = {text = hartmagnetisch}}
                      ]
    data[set = left_soft] {
                           var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                           func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-2 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
                          }
    data[set = right_soft] {
                            var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                            func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-2 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
                           }
    data[set = left_hard] {
                           var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                           func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-.75 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
                          }
    data[set = right_hard] {
                            var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                            func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-.75 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
                           };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I get many

> ! Dimension too large.
>   `\pgfmath@iterate` ...`\pgfmath@xa \ifdim \pgfmath@x`

errors. How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evaluation of `exp(-2 * \value x - 1.5)` for x=-6 and x=-7, and likewise of `exp(-2 * \value x + 1.5)` for x=-5,-6,-7 results in an overflow. The easiest fix is to omit these values since this part of the graph is covered by the other curves anyway. Otherwise you can define the function piece-wise by setting it to zero for the bad values of x.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks and grid = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{H}{\si{\A\per\m}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{B(H)}{\si{\tesla}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {left_soft, right_soft, left_hard, right_hard},
                       left_soft = {style = dashed,
                                    label in legend = {text = weichmagnetisch}
                                   },
                       right_soft = {style = dashed},
                       left_hard = {label in legend = {text = hartmagnetisch}}
                      ]
    data[set = left_soft] {
                           var x : interval [-5 : 7];
                           func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-2 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
                          }
    data[set = right_soft] {
                            var x : interval [-4 : 7];
                            func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-2 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
                          }
    data[set = left_hard] {
                           var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                           func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-.75 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
                          }
    data[set = right_hard] {
                            var x : interval [-7 : 7];
                            func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-.75 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
                           }
;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @gernot! Thank you for your answer! If I understand correctly there is no general solution (like `fpu`) for this task?

Comment: @Su-47 Sorry, I have no experience with `fpu`. It may well be that the calculations can be done with a higher precision/bigger range.