# TikZ datavisualization and Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I'm trying to draw a simple graph using tikz datavisualisation but I run into a "Dimension too large".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
 
     \tikz \datavisualization [scientific axes=clean, visualize as smooth line]
       data [format=function] {
         var x : interval [1338:5500] samples 100;
         func y =  (1000000 / \value{x} - 28 - 137.4) * 64 * 1.25;
       };

\end{document}
```

Any idea on how I can fix this ?

Comment: Hello. can you please provide a fully compilable example so we can run it on our PCs? thank you

Comment: It appears to me that there is a negative value overflow. check this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350016/how-to-draw-a-hysteresis-loop-with-tikz-datavisualization 

and this one 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354071/dimension-too-large-errors-by-tikz-datavisualization

My guess is that when `x` be is small enough, the negative value is really big and causes an overflow.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518311.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally copied from tex.stackexchange.com/a/518311.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [scientific axes=clean, visualize as smooth line,
    /pgf/data/evaluator=\pgfmathparseFPU]
data [format=function] {
  var x : interval [1338:5500] samples 100;
  func y =  (1000000 / \value{x} - 28 - 137.4) * 64 * 1.25;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative with `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                domain =1338:5000,
                samples=100,
            ]
        \addplot[smooth] {1000000 / x - 28 - 137.4) * 64 * 1.25};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```